# Force rel="opener" for links manually opened in new tab

Tags: javascript, html

In my website I have some links like:

```html
<a href="/myhref" target="_blank" rel="opener">My Link</a>
```

I use `rel="opener"` because I need the `sessionStorage` data within the new tab and everything works fine, but I noticed that using the "open link in new tab" command in the right-click menu of the same link hasn't the same behavior.

Looks like the link is opened without the `rel="opener"` attribute, and `sessionStorage` data isn't available in the new tab.

I guess it's something related to security, but in my case it's just an intranet website and I would like to know if there's a way to have the same behavior for both cases.

Thanks

Comment: If you just use `sessionStorage`, then no. Alternatives include `localStorage` and cookies.

Comment: Hey mate, have you found any way to fix this? I am also facing the same issue. Thanks

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapati unfortunately no, sorry

Comment: @Fab no worries, thanks for your reply.